# Catching onHistoryStateUpdated events for all tabs from a background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to catch [`webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) using [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) in my WebExtensions extension.

The problem is, I can catch `onHistoryStateUpdated` events only for the persistent background page that I created to listen `onHistoryStateUpdated` events from **all** other tabs!

`tabs.onUpdated` event works perfectly fine from the background page, but not `onHistoryStateUpdated` -which is crucial as I have to catch browser back/forward events-.

---

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

*background.js*

```
// Works not... (i.e. is not fired)
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log("tabid", tabId);
});


// WORKS!
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {    
    console.log("Tab #" + tabId, " has its URL to: (" + changeInfo.status + ")");
    console.log("\t" + changeInfo.url);
});
```

Comment: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is sufficient to catch all URL changes including history navigation whereas `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` doesn't fire on direct URL hash change like `location.hash = '#newhash'`

Comment: @wOxxOm I understand, but I need to detect whether the URL change was due to back/forward buttons or not (such as JavaScript redirect, clicking on a link etc.)

Comment: Well, you can detect `back` button navigation this way but I'm not so sure about `forward` button: the reported transitionType is `link`. Hmm, maybe coupled with transitionQualifier you'll be able to deduce that. Also, make sure to use [Firefox 48 or newer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onHistoryStateUpdated).

Comment: Another catch: it seems onHistoryStateUpdated isn't fired for the tabs opened before this event listener is attached.

Comment: The fact that it is a forward/back transition is available as an entry in the `transitionQualifiers` array, the value `"forward_back"`, which is provided in the details of the `webNavigation.onCommitted` event. This is true for both Chrome extensions and WebExtensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event_order) and the [WebExtensions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onHistoryStateUpdated) explicitly state that the `webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` event is fired when the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) is used to change the URL in the location bar. Neither states that the event is fired when the user clicks on either the <kbd>forward</kbd> or <kbd>back</kbd> button.

If you want to determine that a navigation was the result of the user clicking on <kbd>forward</kbd> or <kbd>back</kbd>, you will need to listen to [`webNavigation.onCommitted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCommitted) <sup><sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCommitted)</sup></sup> events.  The information is available as the value `"forward_back"` being included in the [`transitionQualifiers`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#type-TransitionQualifier) <sup><sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/transitionQualifier)</sup></sup> array. In such cases, the `transitionType` appears to remain as the method for the browser to have originally been navigated to that URL.